# Number of Kafka consumer's clients decrease after rebalancing

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I've noticed that after a period of time -for example two days- consumergroup concurrency become lower that one I config.

I use spring boot and here is my code sample

```
factory.setConcurrency(10);
```

when I use following kafka command after stating kafka consumer it show exactly 10 different consumer client

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group samplaConsumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

after a period of time when I run upper command consumer clients become lower, for example 6 distinct client and manage those 10 partitions.

how can I fix this so after re-balancing or whatever number of clients remain constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that if a consumer client takes more time than `max.poll.interval.ms` to process the polled data the consumer considers failed and the group will rebalance.

> `max.poll.interval.ms`  The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before the expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

And I found out that if this happens a lot that consumer client considers dead and no more rebalancing happens so the number of consumer concurrent client will decrease.

One solution that I came into is that I can decrease the number of `max.poll.records` so that processing of records took less time than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 50); // default is 200
```